# Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed when using fetch on ReactNative/Node,js/Expo

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

I made a very simple backend application using Node.js and Expo. If I run the backend on my work computer, I get the responses with no issues (I'm using REST Client on vscode for testing). But when I try to run the React Native Android app from my phone using the Expo app with Tunnel Connection, I get the following error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]
at node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:535:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:214:12 in _allocateCallback$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:112:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:357:16 in callTimers
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:417:4 in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:114:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:368:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:113:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

This is my app.js for the backend:

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import morgan from 'morgan';

import swaggerJSDoc from 'swagger-jsdoc';
import swaggerUI from 'swagger-ui-express';
import { options } from './swaggerOptions';
const specs = swaggerJSDoc(options);

import tasksRoutes from './routes/tasks';

const app = express();//This is my app using express, which will listen to the port 3000

app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(tasksRoutes);

app.use('/docs', swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(specs));

export default app;
```

index.js:

```
import app from "./app";

app.listen(3000, '192.168.6.180');//I was using localhost, but changed to my ip address.
console.log('Server on port 3000');
```

routes/tasks.js:

```
import {Router} from 'express';
import {deleteTask, getTask, getTaskCount, getTasks, saveTask, updateTask} from '../controllers/tasks';

const router = Router();

router.get('/tasks', getTasks);
//More calls...

export default router;
```

controllers/tasks.js:

```
import {connect} from '../database';

export const getTasks = async (req, res) => {
    const connection = await connect();
    const[rows] = await connection.query('SELECT * FROM tasks');
    res.json(rows);
};
//More functions...
```

And this is my React Native component where I call the backend:

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

const HomeScreen = () => {

  const loadTasks = async () => {

    const res = await fetch('http://192.168.6.180:3000/tasks');
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);

  }

  useEffect(() => {

    loadTasks();

  }, [])

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

The page loads on my phone, but I can't get the response. I'm testing this on my work. My computer is connected directly by ethernet, and my phone is using wifi to connect to a 'guests' network. That's why I'm using Tunnel connection on Expo instead of LAN.